# How to make Scrollable StaggeredGrid list like Pinteret in flutter

Tags: flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, android-gridview, staggered-gridview

I tried using [flutter_staggered_grid_view 0.6.1](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view)
I was able to create the list but not able to make the list Scrollable.
If there is any other library I can use or is it any other way to make it scrollable.
this version **0.6.1** has made **StaggeredGridList** to non scrollable without and good documentation.

[image]

Also can anyone tell me Why is my custom card height got bad?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class DisplayCard extends StatelessWidget {
  DisplayCard(
      {this.profileImagePath,
      this.captionText,
      this.profileName,
      this.timeStamp});

  final String? profileImagePath;
  final String? profileName;
  final String? captionText;
  final String? timeStamp;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      child: Container(
        height: 190,
        width: 180,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Image(
              image: AssetImage(profileImagePath!),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 7, 5, 2),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 10,
                                  color: Colors.black87,
                                ),
                                children: [
                                  TextSpan(
                                    text: profileName,
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 10,
                                      color: Colors.black87,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  const TextSpan(text: ' '),
                                  TextSpan(text: captionText),
                                ]),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 3.0),
                            child: Text(
                              timeStamp!,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 10,
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    flex: 3,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: AssetImage(profileImagePath!),
                      radius: 13,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      elevation: 10,
      shadowColor: Colors.black,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should use this widget [MasonryGridView](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view#masonry) in that package. I assume you're using [StaggeredGrid](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view#staggered) which is mentioned that not scrollable in the doc. And don't forget to add `itemCount` (it isn't mentioned in the doc) if you know the list length beforehand.
2. The Image height is longer than the Container height.